# How do I find the SNR of an ethernet connection?

Tags: ethernet, signal, ifconfig, signal-strength

`iwconfig` reports the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) of wireless connections, but how do I find the SNR for an ethernet connection? `ifconfig` does not report it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SNR of a wired connection is not known to the kernel, as it is not exposed to any driver ABI. This has to do with the fact, that it is a much less important measure with wired connections, than it is with wireless ones.

AFAIK, no hardware vendor pushes the analog concept of the wire-level SNR into the host-facing digital parts of his circuitry.